# Google API for Internationalization + asp.net

Tags: asp.net, internationalization, google-api

Hai guys,

Is there any google api for Internationalization with asp.net or any other open source api for it because i want my users to view my site in multiple indian languages like tamil,malayalam,hindi,telugu etc... I have seen google use it in http://www.google.co.in/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET includes decent localization features natively - which is probably much easier to work that an external API. Here's an article I wrote some time ago that might help:

http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwDbResourceProvider/introtolocalization.aspx

ASP.NET handles server side localization reasonably well - client side localization is a bit more difficult. For that I actually created a server side resource handler some time ago that allows using server resources on the client side. More info here:

http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/698097.aspx